# Can Javascript applications be hosted on WebSphere, similar to Java applications?

Tags: javascript, websphere, serverside-javascript

I am learning WebSphere and want know if this is possible. I have hosted Java application using WebSphere but do not know if it is possible with other languages, particularly Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, websphere application server doesn't have a server-side javascript programming model.

edit: @SpiderPig points out that (some) JVM's hava javascript interpreters in them that would be accessible in your Java EE code.

Comment: The JVM has a JavaScript interpreter built in. For simple cases that could be sufficient.

Comment: For hosting a Javascript application you may want to look into Strongloop, which does tie into WebSphere Liberty ND's management, allowing you to control both your Java (Liberty) and Javascript (Strongloop) runtimes using a single collective.  (This is also true for Docker containers, so you could run your app in a docker container using w/e js runtime, like regular Node.js)